# Public IP for landscape dashboard

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

We followed following procedure to setup the openstack -
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

We have 5 physical machines:

- machine 1: MAAS deployed, 2 drives and 2 interfaces(public and
  private)   Maas is configured as DHCP and DNS.
- machine 2: Openstack installation, 2 drives and 2 interfaces(public and private)
- machines 3, 4, 5: added to MAAS.

When we run the openstack installation on second machine, its picks up the one node from MAAS that is in **ready state** and starts the deployment of juju.

When the landscape installation completes it returns the private ip for landscape dashboard.  It seems like MAAS DHCP is allocating that private IP.

Our questions:

1. How we can assign the Public IP to landscape so that we can access it from the outside?
2. What's the use of the 2 machines that we have used for openstack installation thus-far. It seems like its deploying everything on the one node from MAAS.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the easiest for now is to access Landscape on the ip address given.  You can use something like [sshuttle](http://www.unixmen.com/sshuttle-poor-mans-vpn-ssh/) or [ssh -D](http://straightedgelinux.com/blog/howto/socks.html) to get access to an environment quite easily with almost no setup.

If you need to create an external IP, the IP address you create needs to be accessible to all the nodes, and the outside.Then you can make a change to the Landscape juju environment like this:

```
export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju
juju set apache2 servername=<hostname-you-want>
```

Follow `juju debug-log` and you should see the charms reacting to the change and updating the root_url correctly.

Once you have access to Landscape, you can continue with installing the OpenStack cloud on the remaining 3 machines.  As it is from your description, it sounds like you have this right now:

- Machine 1: MAAS
- Machine 2: Landscape
- Machines 3-5: unused

When you login to Landscape, you will need to continue following the [instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) on the page you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ought to be able to either...

1) create a file called ~/.juju/openstack.cfg with a section like:
   openstack-dashboard:
     vip: '10.10.10.10'
   ...and then when you deploy the dashboard you'd do so with:
   juju deploy --config=.juju/openstack.cfg openstack-dashboard
   ...which should use the virtual IP address that you've selected.

2) once you've already deployed the dashboard and (if you've also
   deployed juju-gui) then in the Juju-Gui console you'd click
   the Dashboard service, click the Settings button, scroll down
   the panel on the left and look for the VIP setting.  You'd then
   enter the IP address you want and then press any Commit buttons
   that show up.